# Configure Multi Disc Macrium Auto Restore .vbs file

Tags: vbscript

A previous team where I work created a vbs script that can automatically start a restore of a Macrium Image File located on inserted optical media. The problem is that the Macrium Image File is now too big for one disc, and now we have it split onto 2 separate discs, so now the vbs script doesn't function the way it should.

When Automatic Restore is launched, it should detect disc 1, which ends in 00.00.mrimg and know that it is part of a multi-disc install, at which point it asks for the next disc, ending in 00-01.mrimg.

I know this probably makes no sense, especially if anyone reading is not familiar with Macrium. But I will do my best to answer any questions.

I would normally plug away and try to figure it out myself, but i'm not very familiar with VBS and the problem is pretty time sensitive. Any help I can get will be much appreciated.

Opened AutoRestore.vbs script to see if I could fix the issue, but I don't know enough about vbs to fix it.

```
'AutoRestore.vbs
Dim fso, d, dc, s, n , Root, u, racine, folder, folderName, restoreString, foundFile, cdDrive
Dim wipe
Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dc = fso.Drives
foundFile = false
restoreString = "00-00.mrimg"

For Each d in dc
  Root = d.Driveletter & ":"
  racine = d.Driveletter & ":\"

  u= Detect(Root)
  if (( u="CD-ROM") ) then
    cdDrive = cdDrive & racine & " "
    if (d.isReady) then
      folderName = racine & "IAS\"
      Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)
    end if
  end if
Next

If IsNull(folder) or IsEmpty(folder) Then
  MsgBox "Could not locate IAS folder containing restore image." & vbCrLf & "The following optical disk drives were searched: " & cdDrive & vbCrLf & "Please verify the media is the drive or use manual restore.", 48, "Folder Not Found" 
Else
  For each file in folder.Files
    If instr(1,file.Name, restoreString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      return = objShell.run("""%ProgramFiles%\macrium\diskrestore.exe""" & folderName & file.Name & " -r -g -u --targetnum 0 --reboot --eject",1,false)
      foundFile = true
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  if (foundFile = false) Then
    MsgBox "Cannot locate .mrimg file in " & folderName & "." & vbCrLf & "Please use manual restore.", 48, "File Not Found"
  End If
End If

Function Detect(DrivePath)
Dim fso, d, s, t
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set d = fso.GetDrive(fso.GetDriveName(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(DrivePath)))
Select Case d.DriveType
Case 0: t = "Unknown"
Case 1: t = "Removable"
Case 2: t = "Fixed"
Case 3: t = "Network"
Case 4: t = "CD-ROM"
Case 5: t = "RAM Disk"
End Select
Detect = t
End Function
```

Expected Results: Run AutoRestore.vbs, the script sees the 00-00.mrimg file in IAS folder of the optical media, then prompts to insert the optical media containing the 00-01.mrimg file.

Actual Results: Run AutoRestore.vbs, then Macrium states "Backup set is not complete. At least one file may be missing."

Answer (score 0):

You could first copy all the mrimg files to a temporary folder on the machine's hard drive. Once you have them all, you can then run Disk Restore with that folder instead of the CD-ROM drive.

Most of your existing code would work. After the `For Each d in dc` loop, you know the drive where the discs are being inserted. You could add another loop:

```
Dim tempFolder
Set tempFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\AutoRestore\")

Do While MsgBox("Please insert disc and click OK. When all discs have been inserted, click Cancel", vbOKCancel, "Auto Restore") = vbOK

    For Each file In folder.Files
        If InStr(1, file.Name, ".mrimg") > 0 Then
            ' Copy file to Temp folder
            fso.CopyFile file.Path, tempFolder.Path & "\", True
        End If
    Next

Loop
```

After this, you should have all the mrimg files in the `tempFolder` location. I am not familiar with the parameters the Marcium command expects but this is where you would specify the new folder:

```
objShell.run("""%ProgramFiles%\macrium\diskrestore.exe""" & tempFolder.Path & "\" & file.Name & " -r -g -u --targetnum 0 --reboot --eject",1,false)
```

Comment: Etienne, I like the idea of copying the image files to the local machine. I just gave it a try but the script is still looking for the image files in the E: drive(CD-ROM). How to I get it to look for the image files which I have now copied to the D: drive?